# Servlet POST parameters null

Tags: forms, servlets, null, parameters

I want a servlet to print the parameters from a html form but in the servlet the request has no parameters.

```
<form method="post" action="LoginServlet" >
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and the servlet's doPost():

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("POST");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String redirectUrl;

    Enumeration atributes = request.getAttributeNames();
    while (atributes.hasMoreElements()) {

        System.out.println((String )atributes.nextElement()+ ".");
    }
    String user = (String) request.getAttribute("username");
    String pass = (String) request.getAttribute("password");
    System.out.println("user:" + (String) request.getAttribute("username"));

}
```

So it doesn't output any parameters and the username parameters is NULL.

Comment: I think this is an inappropriate question. Dont have enough reputation to vote it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are parameters - use [`getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)).